# Create timelapse iterating through directories with Python linux

Tags: python, linux, directory, raspberry-pi, timelapse

I'm trying to write a program where I iterate through directories, and in each sub directory I create a timelapse with the images inside the folder.

This is what I have for now:

```
import os

#iterating through directories
RootDir='/home/pi/TestMultFolder/RootDir'

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(RootDir)


 filepath=subdir
    print filepath
    #create Timelapse
    os.system("avconv -r 10 -i Img_%04d.jpg -r 10 -vcodec libx264 -crf 20 -g 15 timelapse.mp4")
```

This prints the correct subdirectories, but does not do the timelapse. The timelapse command works if I do it in a single folder.
I'm using a Raspberry Pi v3.

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind found out what was wrong. Here's why for any who's interested:

I simply did not change directory to execute command. So I added an os.chdir(filepath)

```
import os

#iterating through directories
RootDir='/home/pi/TestMultFolder/RootDir'

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(RootDir)
    filepath=subdirs+'/'
    print filepath
    #create Timelapse
    os.chdir(filepath)
    os.system("avconv -r 10 -i Img_%04d.jpg -r 10 -vcodec libx264 -crf 20 -g 15 timelapse.mp4")
```

Answer (score -2):

You misused os.walk, waht you call subdir is actually the root directory, you should use it like :

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(RootDir):
```

and you will find your subdirs in dirs.

Comment: This is a very incomplete answer, and doesn't explain how to do what the OP is asking.